# Supervised Machine Learning Prediction to pyautogui

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, knn, pyautogui

I'm a newbie to Machine Learning.

I'm making a smart glove to recognise different hand gesture using KNN classifier. So far I've successfully typed out the code and been able to predict the correct gesture that I input.

**Now, I want to use the package pyautogui to connect the gesture with some actual function so as to control the computer**

(i.e. if the classifier predicted the gesture as gesture "A", I want it to be a left click function.)

But I'm not quite sure if it's possible and how I can to do that.
The type of the prediction I get is "numpy.ndarray"

Answer (score 0):

Each of the numpy arrays you get in the output from the KNN is unique.So you can map all the array outputs to some pre-defined values
For each of the gesture define functions which you want like:

```
if gesture_1==True:
  pos=pyautogui.position() # to get the position tuple of the cursor
  pyautogui.click(pos[0],pos[1]) #to click at that left-position
```